# Latin phrase for "at the moment" or "immediate", temporal equivalent for in situ?

Tags: phrases, latin

I know phrases like "in situ" which means in the current place/position, is there another phrase for the temporal equivalent which means "at the moment"?

Comment: You should ask here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It appears that the OP is seeking a phrase of Latin origin that would be, like *in situ*, readily understood in an English context; so interpreted, the question is about English language and usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard the Latin phrase **pro tempore** or more usually **pro tem** used in English, meaning "for the time being."

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_tempore).